# Slding form does not show one form at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a sliding form with jQuery, but the forms aren't being shown one at a time, they show all at once. Yet, jsfiddle corrects the problem. Not sure how.

Comment: Provide some more info please, link to the working fiddle and the not working html page so we can check it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/713Marketing/Awh3G/117/ @Ineentho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you view source from the viewing frame of JSFiddle, this is the difference: http://diffchecker.com/3q359BDH. A working example using JSFiddles code: http://teswo.tk/so/1.html